# Checksum calculation for ROM memory

Tags: embedded, interrupt, interrupt-handling, flash-memory, rom

I am using controller STM32Lxx. During the calculation of ROM memory checksum missing interrupts(In LIN bus is not responding properly.)

How to avoid this scenario?
I thought to calculate a checksum for a small portion of ROM then----> finally add all these checksum values.

is there any other method to overcome this issue?

Comment: Why are you checking the ROM while trying to run the LIN bus?  It is normally something you do on start-up before starting the application.  That said I would question the merit of verifying ROM in any case.  Given that your code is running from ROM, if it has failed, what is the likelihood the test code will run in any case?  Moreover if you miss interrupts because you are running other code, then there is something seriously wrong with your design - such as running the test itself from an interrupt!

Comment: @Clifford - For example in safety-related systems, re-checking the ROM CRC during runtime is a completely normal measure that is even (more or less) enforced by standards like IEC 61508. The benefit is that the system is able (with some useful probability) to put itself into a safe state while only parts of the ROM are broken whose code is not currently executed. Of course, you'll not achieve a diagnostic coverage of 100% this way.

Comment: @Raju Dasar - We'll need additional information on your problem: How do you calculate your ROM checksum (pure software or CRC peripheral, with or without DMA)? How do you process the LIN bus (with/without DMA and/or interrupts)? What kind of scheduling do you use? I have the feeling that LIN and CRC calculation are interfering some way in your software, even if both parts are quite unrelated.